# Best title text for accessible PDF link

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink, accessibility, wcag2.0

I am working on doing accessibility remediation to several websites based off WCAG 2.0 AA standards. These sites have quite a lot of links to PDFs. Here is a common example of what they have:

```
<a href="/assets/pdf/pdf-file.pdf" target=_blank">Get Blah Information</a>
```

Based on my best understanding of WCAG 2.0 AA principles, this links should have `title` text added, becoming something like:

```
<a href="/assets/pdf/pdf-file.pdf" target=_blank" title="Opens PDF file in a new window">Get Blah Information</a>
```

My question is about this `title` text. It only seems occasionally appropriate. Most browsers will open the `target="_blank"` in a new tab, not a new window. Also, on mobile many devices will launch a native app to open the PDF. Some devices/browsers will actually download the file, depending on the settings. With all these considerations, is there a better, more universal title for these types of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally considered courteous to give people a heads-up that that what they are clicking on will not open up as a webpage.

In my organization, we require that PDF links (or any link pointing to a non-HTML document) needs to clearly annotate the file type in the anchor text.

Like this:
`<a href="/assets/pdf/pdf-file.pdf">Get Blah Information (PDF)</a>`

The `title` attribute isn't consistently supported among screen-reader/browser combinations, so I wouldn't recommend depending on it to work.

> **Links to Non-HTML Resources**
>   https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/hypertext_links#non_html
>
> Users should generally be alerted to links that lead to non-HTML resources, such as PDF files, Word files, PowerPoint files, and so on. However, there is some debate as to whether the content author or the browser should be the one to alert the user. The trouble is that none of the browsers or screen readers currently alert the user at all, so the debate is more theoretical than practical.

If you're opposed to putting the filetype in the anchor text, you could always use the `aria-label` attribute to supplement the anchor text, or [position the text off screen](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#absolutepositioning) so that it's not visible to sighted users, although these solutions may be less accessible for users with limited-sight ability.

Comment: I like how WebAIM (provided link in your answer) shows how images can be used within the link to show different behavior. The image alt covered screen readers and it is much more space conservative within the link. Thanks, Josh!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the `title` attribute in this case. There are several issues with its use, and it should be avoided in most cases. For example, screen reader software will often read the title attribute in addition to the text that is already in the link, thus reading redundant and potentially confusing text. The way that the `title` attribute is handled is inconsistent across assistive technology. [Read more about when to use and not use the title attribute](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/).

Additionally, I would avoid describing the action that will take place. As you described, different technology/devices handle the link in different ways, and the user can even choose how to interact with the link (open in a new tab, etc). Instead, focus on describing the purpose of the link. Your first example: `<a href="/assets/pdf/pdf-file.pdf" target=_blank">Get Blah Information</a>` is much better than the second.

Comment: Interesting. I read your link and that was good info about the title attribute. However, using target="_blank" seems to be good practice with links, and that creates a context change that some users won't know, such as screen readers. In my case creating long and verbose link text is not an option without rebuilding parts of the site. Isn't the title attribute there to serve in those cases?

Comment: The browser will handle the change of context in the case of activating a link with `target="_blank"` while using a screen reader. So screen reader users will know about it anyway. If you must create a screen reader only version of link text, the `aria-label` attribute is better, but then you have to maintain two strings (and it is easy to forget about the accessibile only string).